# Python multiprocessing with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, multiprocessing, mod-wsgi

I wrote a python script that runs a set of queries in parallel using multiprocessing.pool and map_async. It works perfectly when I run it from the command prompt.
But when trying tu run it from Apache / mod_wsgi it has worked only 2 times, and since that it no longer works. The web page still loading and I get no error in return.

Here is the python scipt:

```
import os, sys
from pywps import Process, LiteralInput, LiteralOutput, ComplexInput, ComplexOutput, Format, FORMATS
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pg import DB
import datetime
import json
from functools import partial
db = DB(dbname='***', host='***' port=***, user='***', passwd='***')

def calc_ttop(tabcouv, code):
    db.query(""" INSERT INTO ttop.ttop_all..."""% (tabcouv, code, code))

class Ttop(Process):
      def __init__(self):

      inputs = [LiteralInput('input1', 'description input1', data_type='string')]
      outputs = [LiteralOutput('output1',
                             'description output1', data_type='string'),
                ComplexOutput('output2', 'description output2',
                             supported_formats=[
                                        Format('application/text')
                                        ]
                             )]

     super(Ttop, self).__init__(
         self._handler,
         identifier="ttop", 
         version = "0.1",
         title="",
         store_supported = True,
         status_supported = True,
         inputs=inputs,
         outputs=outputs,
         abstract="Ce web service WPS permet de calculer le ttop"
     )

 def _handler(self, request, response):

     time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
     q = db.query("""
                SELECT distinct code_c from table_c limit 500
                """)
     tup = q.getresult()
     code_com = list(zip(*tup)[0])

     db.query("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ttop.ttop_all""")
     db.query("""
                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ttop.ttop_all 
                    (
                    ...
                    )
              """)
     pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=7)
     func = partial(calc_ttop, request.inputs['input1'][0].data)
     pool.map_async(func, code_com)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()

     outlist = db.query("""
            SELECT * from ttop.ttop_all_4g
            """)
     out = outlist.getresult()

     response.outputs['output1'].data = "Temps de traitement : " + str(datetime.datetime.now()-time1)+"\n"
     response.outputs['output2'].data = out
     return response
```

And this is how I call the python web service :
http://myhost/wps?service=WPS&request=Execute&version=1.0.0&identifier=ttop&DataInputs=input1=table1

Is there a problem when using python multiprocessing with Apache ?

I use Apache 2.4.6, Python 2.7.5 and Redhat 7

Comment: Where is the code in question? What have you tried so far? Can you show a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I edited the question, thanks

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to do anything that spawns off new processes from inside a web application hosted by a WSGI server. You should look at an external queueing system such as Celery.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I'm using PyWPS witch run as a WSGI application on apache2 or nginx. So I'm afraid I have to use WSGI.
I can't see how Celery can be a solution in this case

Comment: You still have your web application, but instead of running stuff using multiprocessing from the web application, you queue a job up with Celery or some other separate task queuing and execution system. That separate task execution system then runs the job and returns the result to your web application. Forking processed from a web server process is generally not a good idea and may not always work or could potentially interfere with the operation of the web server if not careful. Best to avoid it.

Comment: Will Celery replace multiprocessing?
Can you please provide an example?
I'm getting lost in the Celery documentation. Thanks !